# How to apply class to form label?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this in a twig.

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.name, {'attr':{'class':'admin_finance_input'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.amount, {'attr':{'class':'admin_finance_input'}}) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Can anybody tell me how to set a class for form_label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By checking the block_label from form_div_layout.html(https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) you see this:

```
 <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {% endif %}
```

so you can do this

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {'label_attr ':{'class':'admin_finance_input'}}) }}
```

Comment: thanks mate, actually I always made tricky css stuffs to put style on my labels.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Joao answer,

You are able to configure class attribute (and other html attributes if wanted) also when decomposing a form row :

```
<div class='form_row'>
    <div class="error">{{ form_errors(form.name) }}</div>
    {{ form_label(form.name, 'Choose a name:', 'attr': {'class': 'admin_finance_label'}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
</div>
```